# how to get current location instead off map latlng

Tags: dictionary, location, geo

how can add current location on map default
show me only latlng show here

$(document).ready(function() {

```
var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418); //Google map Coordinates
var map;

map_initialize(); // initialize google map

//############### Google Map Initialize ##############
function map_initialize()
{
        var googleMapOptions = 
        { 
            center: mapCenter, // map center
            zoom: 17, //zoom level, 0 = earth view to higher value
            maxZoom: 18,
            minZoom: 16,
            zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL //zoom control size
        },
            scaleControl: true, // enable scale control
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP // google map type
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("google_map"), googleMapOptions);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please replace the unexpected `dictionary` keyword by the more adapted `google-maps` keyword.

Comment: Would you to replace the default mapCenter `google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418);` by your own coordinates ?

Comment: no it not work. i want basically get current location on map when open and drop pin

Comment: To answer to we need at least to know what is the device where google.maps works in order to know how to get the current location.